# Office Web Apps and SharePoint 2013 Integration Questions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, irm

I have a few questions regarding document access using Office Web Apps and Sharepoint 2013. (As a note I also have ADRMS and IRM configured)

Is it possible to restrict a certain group of users only to be able to open and edit a document in office web apps?

Can you restrict the ability to download a document to the same group?

Is it possible to disable/hide the print option in office web apps?